# Trying to prevent users from being redirected with an ad by blocking any redirection without the user clicking on a link

Tags: javascript, redirect, ads

So I have a website where my users are being redirected by spam ads. The ad network I am using are trying to find them. But these bad ads keep coming back even when the ad networks removes them. So I am looking for a solution that will prevent these ads to redirect my users.

Here is what I have tried with JS:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
      return 'Dialog text here.';
    };

window.onclick = function(e) {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
};

window.location = 'http://google.com/';
```

I am also thinking of using sandbox on the iframes but I am unsure if the ad networks will be too happy about this.

For some reason the JS still redirects the page to Google without asking if the user wants to be redirected.

Basically I am trying to let users click around without getting the popup to ask them if they want to be redirected. But if any other way is used they get the popup.

Comment: If this ad network can't police its own clients properly, you should motivate them by using a different ad network.

Comment: We are clearly not the only ones: http://techcrunch.com/2014/01/06/shady-app-install-ads-are-automatically-redirecting-mobile-users-to-app-store-google-play/ There is got to be some solution to this.

Comment: It's not your solution to find.

Comment: I am getting punish. But I see what you mean.